# WCF SOAP, WSDL defines a integer parameter, but service demands a blank. How?

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

So, I am tasked with integrating with a 3rd party web service. The WSDL for the service has an operation, where the input parameter is defined like so (variable names changed for anonymity/legality) :

```
    <xs:complexType name="RequestData_Type">
     <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="A" type="tns:string8"/>
      <xs:element name="B" type="tns:integer11"/>
      <xs:element name="C" type="tns:integer11"/>
      <xs:element name="D" type="tns:string21"/>
      <xs:element name="E" type="tns:string13"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Integer11 is defined as :

```
<xs:simpleType name="integer11">
 <xs:restriction base="xs:long">
  <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
  <xs:maxInclusive value="99999999999"/>
 </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

When I imported this WSDL into visual studio (Add Web Reference), it generated a proxy class that has the following fields (properties excluded for readability)

```
public partial class RequestData_Type : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private string A;

        private long B;

        private long C;

        private string D;

        private string E;
```

And finally, the message that the web service ***ACTUALLY*** wants to receive is

```
  <RequestData>
         <A>SomeData</A>
         <B> </B>
         <C> </C>
         <D> </D>
         <E>SomeData</E>
      </RequestData>
```

So, In my opinion, this is completely invalid, because B and C are defined as integers, are not defined as nillable, and are not defined as MinOccurs=0

I raised this issue to the 3rd party that owns the service/wsdl and they basically replied back as : "Nobody else has problems, deal with it, we suggest turning off schema validation".  Joy.

So steps to resolve :

I tried manually tweaking the proxy to be "long?".  That generated

```
     <B xsi:nil="true" xmlns=""/>
```

Web service pukes on that.

tweaked the proxy to be string (!). With a null value of the string, the property dropped out of the generated XML all together. Web service pukes on that.

Set the value of the string to " " (space). Xml generates as

```
<B> </B>
```

Web service Happy. Developer Sad.

Am I missing something? Is there some magic wand I can wave during WSDL import that makes this work?  Some configuration I can set on my proxy? I don't think there is, but I want to do the due diligence to make sure I'm not missing anything before I escalate further.

My workaround incredibly kludgy imo.  The real problem with it is, if I can't trust the contracts (of which there are MANY I have to integrate with), all of my development estimates just went out the window. This first integration should have been a few minutes work. Import wsdl. Set property values. Call method. Instead it was 2 hours of tweaking the code repeatedly , capturing the payload in Fiddler,  and running tests manually in SoapUI to figure out what was being sent, and what the service actually demanded.

In this particular use case of this method, the string kludge works. But in if a requirement down the road requires me to actually send that parameter, now I have a property that I think is a string, that is actually an integer. (I suppose I could wrap the string field in a second integer parameter, but that's more kludge)

On top of that, the 3rd party has been changing the WSDL as their development process continues, (which is expected for this project), but every time they add a property or something, I have to re-import the WSDL, which means all my manual tweaks need to be redone.

Help?

Comment: Sounds like the problem here was your original estimate. When has integrating to a third party service ever been as simple as a few minutes work? The problem appears to be a side-effect of the fact that their own deployed service clearly does not conform with the contract they are providing you. So you cannot reliably use the contract to generate your consumer code. One thing you could do is ask them for a sample client, take the model for that into your code, and then consume the service using ChannelFactory<T> rather than having to worry about the service reference.

Comment: My estimates are a lot larger than a few minutes. What I meant by that was that my "get a quick and dirty, happy-path, test working" should be a few minutes. And that SHOULD be.

Comment: Agree it should be - that was kind of the whole purpose of SOAP and WSDL.